# how to avoid line breaks after a hidden image is revealed?

Tags: html, image, whitespace, line-breaks, rollover

I'm working with a list of links that reveal an image when hovered.
However when the image is revealed and subsequently hidden a line break is left. Is there any way to avoid this?

Here are some images to show the exact problem:

Before: http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e126/aaron123456/Screenshot2011-11-10at155956.png

After the images are revealed: http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e126/aaron123456/Screenshot2011-11-10at160023.png

I'm pretty new to coding, any help you can give would be great.
thanks!

Comment: this is during the images are revealed http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e126/aaron123456/Screenshot2011-11-10at160017.png (only allowed to post two hyperlinks max in the question)

Comment: Please post your source code here. And/or usage of jsfiddle.net would be useful.

Comment: with this as html '<span id="hover_img"><a href="?p=11">hover!<img src="../images/thumbs/madnanna.jpg" alt="" /></a></span><br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/csPw2/

html

```
<span id="hover_img">Hover!<img src="http://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="image" /></span>
<br />
<a href="#">Link1</a><br />
<a href="#">Link1</a><br />
...
```

css

```
#hover_img img {
    display: none;
}
#hover_img:hover img {
    display: block;
}
#hover_img:hover + br {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work :c there's still a line break after you reveal the image. the links all move down a space. thanks for you're help though, it's a weird one

Comment: As I see, in this jsfiddle.net/csPw2/ `</br>` after the image is gone. So there is some other problem. Post, link all your code.

Comment: oh yeah it works on firefox fine. ive been using safari, doesnt work on safari for some reason

Comment: fixed it. changed the span to a div, seems to be working ok. thanks again for your help!